# Having trouble with composite functions, inverse functions. Have an example question from upcoming test.

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Here is a look at what I am doing. The I can evaluate the first one no problem. The second one is causing me problems and the solution given isn't helping me to get my head around it. Can someone please try and give me the steps and an explanation? Thanks

[image: Sample Question and solution]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you having trouble finding the inverse function or the composition?

Comment: I think an explanation of Evaluate the following:

(f1^-1 . f2)

The solution doesn't really help me to work out how to get there. It is probably the inverse I'm having issues with because I'm not sure how to calculate it..

Comment: Whoever downvoted, come on, it's a new user!

Comment: Alright. Then let's consider the $f_1$. Given $y=3x+2$, can you find $x$ in terms of $y$?

Answer (score 1):

If $y=f_1(x)=3x+2$, then $y-2=3x$ and $x=\frac13(y-2)$, so $f^{-1}(y)=\frac13(y-2).$

To calculate $f_1^{-1}(f_2(1.9))$, first calculate $f_2(1.9)=4\times1.9^3=27.436$.

Now calculate $f_1^{-1}(f_2(1.9))=f_1^{-1}(27.436)=\frac13(27.436-2)\approx8.479.$

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

For the second problem, you are given
\begin{align}
f_{1}(x) &=3x+2 \\
f_{2}(x) &=4x^3 
\end{align}
and you are asked to find $$(f_{1}^{-1}\circ f_{2})(1.9).$$  To do this, you will need to first find the inverse function of $f_{1}(x)$.  To do that, we can take the equation $y = 3x+2$ and solve for $y$:
\begin{align}
y &= 3x + 2\\
y - 2 &=3x\\
\frac{1}{3}(y - 2) &= x.
\end{align}
This tells you that the inverse function is given by the equation $$f_{1}^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{3}(y-2),$$
or to keep the input notation the same with all your functions, we can write this as $$f_{1}^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{3}(x-2)$$ as they did in the solution.  Then, to evaluate \begin{align}
(f_{1}^{-1}\circ f_{2})(1.9) &= f_{1}^{-1}(f_{2}(1.9)).
\end{align}
This means we first need to evaluate $f_{2}(1.9)$.  This gives us $$f_{2}(1.9) = 4(1.9)^{3} = 27.436,$$ which leaves us with $f_{1}^{-1}(27.436)$.  To evaluate that, we use the inverse function we found, so $$f_{1}^{-1}(27.436) = \frac{1}{3}(27.436 - 2) = 8.478$$ to three decimal places.  So, all in all, we have that $$(f_{1}^{-1}\circ f_{2})(1.9) = 8.478$$ to three decimal places.

Comment: Thank you, this has cleared it up aswell!